# Move unknown number of files using wildcard via VBScript (VBS)

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to move one or more files from one directory to another directory using a wildcard:

```
dim filesys 
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If filesys.FileExists("Z:\somepath\somefile_*_A.xlsm") Then 
    filesys.MoveFile "Z:\somepath\somefile_*_A.xlsm", "Z:\destpath\" 
End If
```

And it doesn't work...

Notes:

There are other files in these directories that I do not want to move. I want to move all of the files that are returned using the wildcard. Must be using VBS.

Links:

[VBscript to move files from one directory to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342121/vbscript-to-move-files-from-one-directory-to-another)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: And, the question is ....

Comment: edited the post: it doesn't work

Comment: `FileExists` does not allow wildcard usage. You can write your own version, or remove the test for file existence and handle the possible error in `MoveFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function ShowFolderList(folderspec)

Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)

Set fc = f.Files

For Each f1 in fc

  s = s & f1.name 

  s = s & "<BR>"

Next

ShowFolderList = s

End Function
```

This is from Help. There are no wildcards in FSO. You have to do it yourself. So test if f1.name meets your requirements then copy that file.

Comment: Hey thanks. Looking at this now. Could you share with me what "Help" you are referring to? Thanks!

Comment: You link to the help in your post. It's available as a help file. You can download the whole website if you want. I have it in the Windows Vista SDK (each version includes all previous versions, ie it only grows). I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a wildcard to findfiles imo. 
You could do the check yourself

```
    For Each file In filessys.GetFolder("Z:\somepath").Files
        If( <do your checks on file.Name, might be a regex or a simple string compare>) Then            
            filesys.MoveFile file, "Z:\destpath\" 
        End If
    Next
```

Depending on how much you know about the format of the file it might be enough to just check the [rightmost characters](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_right.asp) if they are always "_A.xlsm" or you can use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)